# Where can I find Serialized item in Azure portal in Sitecore 9.0.2?

Tags: azure, unicorn, serialization, azure-devops

We are using the `Azure portal for Sitecore 9.0.2` instance and using Unicorn along with it.

Where can I find the serialized items in the Sitecore instance?

I checked the path `\\App_Data folder` but it does not have a serialization folder in it.

Are the serialized files created in some other location in Azure?

Comment: try checking the "sourcefolder" parameter from showconfig.aspx , there could be a custom folder name to which the unicorn yml files have been copied over.

Also , is this a environment to which your CI/CD is deploying the files ?

Comment: Hi Abhay..I cannot find any source folder parameter in the showconfig.aspx

Comment: then you need to check how your files getting copied over to the azure app services

Comment: This all depends on how you've configured it. By default, Unicorn will store and look for files in /App_Data/Unicorn.